# How to run a 220v mini split on 110v wired home

Tags: electrical, wiring, air-conditioning, 240v

I have an off grid apt in Baja California Mexico. The apt is wired for 110v. I would like to integrate an ac200max solar generator as well as a 550w dual dual generator.

How can I integrate all of this components?

How can I run a 220v mini split?

Comment: Get a 110/120v mini split.  Problems solved.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. This is _far_ too broad for us to answer all in one shot. Please take the [tour], then read through [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit] this down to one particular, specific thing you've got a question about. You're welcome to make multiple question posts, but just not all in one.

Comment: @isherwood Well, **on-grid** electric customers may get 127V/220V service but I somehow doubt the OP has 127V inverters or generators at their off-grid location.

Comment: Can you explain a little more how/why an apartment "is wired for" anything if it is off grid and apparently has no source of power?  Or ... if it does have power, what is it? What does it even mean to be wired for 110V if you are off grid and have not installed any power?

Comment: Thanks for asking. The area where I live is outside the town I currently live in. I've asked the person building my apt. to wire it so when the town gets on the grid, the house will be wired for when this happens. Hope this helps

Comment: Is that generator 550W or 5500W @OMG?

Comment: So is it effectively a condo (an apartment is conventionally a place you rent from someone else)?

Answer (score 6):

You don't.

The problem is partly 110 vs. 220 (120 vs. 240 in the US, I don't know if your local standard voltage is really 110/220 or 120/240, but that is pretty much a non-issue.)

The problem is the total amount of power. In the US most 240V devices use a **lot** of power. In most cases, if a device needs 1500W or less to run then it is simply put on a 120V 15A or 20A circuit. Sometimes even a bit more (e.g., up to 1,920W continuous on a 120V 20A circuit). So that implies (the specs would say for sure) that a typical 220V minisplit will draw *at least* 2000W.

The "solar generator" is only rated for 120V, ~ 2000W. It isn't a generator, it is a battery pack.

No idea what the 550W dual generator is. But 550W is only a quarter, at best, of the constant supply needed by a 220V minisplit.

Rethink the entire plan. If you have lots of actual solar power available (i.e., you have or can put in a decent amount of solar panels) then that opens up some options. Otherwise, consider a larger generator. If you can get fuel (propane tank or gasoline) then you can use a much larger generator - which will cost a lot less than the "solar generator" and run the 220V minisplit and everything else without a problem, except that you have to keep buying fuel.

But you can't get something for nothing. You need lots of input (solar or fuel) to generate lots of output.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Very insightful

Answer (score 1):

Since you are off grid, you have no need to mess with the odd 127/220V 3-phase power unless you have a generator that makes that.  I would use the American 120/240V system because hardware is readily available north and I expect south of the border.  Half of it is made there lol.

I bet even in apartments using 127/220V, they deliver 2 of 3 phases to any given apartment, using common 120/240V gear.

On the "solar generator", those things are extremely overpriced and hokey, and the marketing is misleading about their abilities. If you want a built-in solar/battery solution like a PowerWall, then get it, but trying to fake it with "solar generators" will not work.

If your generator is 5500W and 120/240V, that will run your 220V heat pump just fine, but you will need a 120/240V distribution panel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your imput